# Event inside a jquery plugin only uses last selector used by plugin?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.fn.testPlugin  = function(options) {
        this.each(function() {
            $$ = this;
            $(window).on('scroll',function() {
                console.log($$);
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery, window, document)
$("#block1").testPlugin();
$("#block2").testPlugin();
<script>
```

why does it only show only #block2 element instead of logging both block1 and block 2?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `$$` is defined as global (window in case of browser) instead of local(due to the absence of var), which causes its value to be of the last element that uses the plugin, overwriting any other previous ones. Just define it with `var` inside the plugin function and it should work fine.

```
this.each(function () {
            var $$ = this; //<-- Here
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                console.log($$);
            })
        });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reELm/)**